# Apache Spark - Tweets Processing

Tags: scala, apache-spark, tweets

Given a huge dataset of tweets i need to:

- extract and count the hashtags.
- extract and count the emoticons/emojis.
- extract and count the words (lemmas)

So, the first thing that came to my mind is doing something like that:

```
val tweets = sparkContext.textFile(DATASET).cache

val hashtags = tweets
                .map(extractHashTags)
                .map((_, 1))
                .reduceByKey(_ + _)

val emoticonsEmojis = tweets
                .map(extractEmoticonsEmojis)
                .map((_, 1))
                .reduceByKey(_ + _)

val lemmas = tweets
                .map(extractLemmas)
                .map((_, 1))
                .reduceByKey(_ + _)
```

But in this way each tweet is processed 3 times, is it right? If so, is there an efficient way to count all these elements separately by processing each tweet only once?

I was thinking something like that:

```
sparkContext.textFile(DATASET)
    .map(extractor) // RDD[(List[String], List[String], List[String])]
```

But in this way it becomes a nightmare. Also because once i count the words (I refer to the third point of the requests), I would need to make a join with another RDD and this, in the first version, is very simple while in the second version is not.

Comment: Are you stuck with the `RDD` API, or can you use the new `Dataframe`/`Dataset` API?

Comment: I'd rather stick with  RDDs because most of the application uses RDDs. But if there is a good solution with the Dataframes, I could always switch.

Comment: As long as you have simple types in a `Dataframe`, it's easy to pull out a typed `RDD` with `df.as[(String, Long)].rdd`. It's possible with complex types, but a bit more difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Dataset API:

```
val tweets = sparkContext.textFile(DATASET)

val tokens = tweets.flatMap(extractor) //return RDD[(String, String)]
  .toDF("type", "token") //type is one of ("hashtag", "emoticon", "lemma")
  .groupBy("type", "token")
  .count() //Dataset[Row] which has columns ("type", "token", "count")

val lemmas = tokens
  .where($"type" === lit("lemma"))
  .select("token", "count")
  .as[(String, Long)]
  .rdd //should be the same type as your original 'lemmas', for future join
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this?

```
sealed trait TokenType { }
object Hashtag extends TokenType
object Emoji extends TokenType
object Word extends TokenType

def extractTokens(tweet: String): Seq[(TokenType, String)] = {
  ...
}

val tokenCounts = tweets
                  .flatMap(extractTokens)
                  .map((_, 1))
                  .reduceByKey(_ + _)

val hashtagCounts = tokenCounts.collect { case ((Hashtag, x), count) => (x, count) }
// similar for emojis and words
```

Comment: This is definitely cleaner than using strings to identify the type, but similar in concept.